# Reading URL goes wrong

Tags: java, json, url, stream, httpurlconnection

I would like to read `https://www.instagram.com/mobonews/?__a=1` using Java language. The source code of following URL is equal to:

```
{"logging_page_id":"profilePage_1410389643","show_suggested_profiles":false,"show_follow_dialog":false,"graphql":{"user":{"biography":"\u200f\u200e\u0645\u0627\u062c\u0631\u0627\u062c\u0648\u06cc\u06cc\u200c\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0645\u0646 \u062f\u0631 \u062
```

But the following code returns this instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in client-root">    <head>        <meta charset="utf-8">        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">        <title>Login • Instagram</title>                <meta name="robots" content="noimageindex, noarchive">        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">        <meta id="viewport" name="viewport"
```

Here is the code I used:

```
    URL website = new URL(url);
    URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                connection.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        response.append(inputLine);
```

**EDIT:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class TestReadurlInsta {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
  URL u = new URL("https://www.instagram.com/mobonews/?__a=1");

URLConnection con = u.openConnection();
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
String encoding = con.getContentEncoding(); 
encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding;
String body = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
System.out.println(body);
    
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

It seems that I get the login page of instagram for unknown reasons:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in client-root">     <head>         <meta charset="utf-8">         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">          <title> Login • Instagram </title>
```

In the past I ran same code from same machine and itt was alright but suddenly it gets me into this problem.

**EDIT 3**:

I ran same code from an online IDE and have received following exception. Seems refused to get a connection and as @Holger said, there might be a prevention from Instagram to access the resource:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: www.instagram.com
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:14)
```

But is there any solution to this?

Comment: I ran your code and it returned the input you want. Check that you're passing the correct string or keep debugging your code.

Comment: @Raz I did check again but still no luck

Comment: But how do you pass url? can you attach more parts of your code or add some data while debugging your program?

Comment: @Raz Please see my edit

Comment: Has Instagram published a policy regarding repeated automated access to such feed resources? For its ordinary web pages, I also get a forced login page after some accesses and you say, you ran the same code from the same machine before. So that would not be that unusual (and explains why all other users can’t reproduce the problem when trying the URL—for their first time).

Comment: @Holger I am not aware of it. But I cannot get access even for my very first try.

Comment: @Holger can you please read my new Edit?

Comment: I don't think that your new error has something to do with Instagram, although Instagram might have something like @Holger mentioned, maybe you made too many requests to Instagram. From Java docs it seems that your exceptions is thrown when IP of url cannot be determined which doesn't sound like what we described, I would believe the òpenConnection` will fail but it throws IO Exception.

Comment: @Raz But after months, in my first try I get a forced login page and that error is made from a online IDE not from my desktop one.

Answer (score 0):

I passed the url as a string to the function and used the bufferedReader.
It seems like you just print the body of the page so you don't get the source.

Here's the code I used

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String str = getContent("https://www.instagram.com/mobonews/?__a=1");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    public static String getContent(String url) throws IOException {
        URL website = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine = "";
        
            inputLine = in.readLine();

        while(inputLine != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
            inputLine = in.readLine();
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using your code still got the same wrong output. I actually used my code several months ago and it worked just fine but now it suddenly returns wrong output. I have no idea why

Comment: @lonesome What happens when you just access the mentioned URL with your browser?

Comment: @lonesome How do you run your code? Does it go through some machine that might no access Instagram correctly?

Comment: I checked just now. I am logged in into insta and I use NetBeans as my IDE

Comment: The returned code actually shows HTML code of log in page of instagram:
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in client-root">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <title>
Login • Instagram
</title>
`

Comment: @lonesome Maybe you should try running it from a different IDE or a different computer

Comment: I just want to know why it suddenly changed like this.

Comment: @lonesome I understand but I believe that it might be related to your computer or IDE. Maybe something you're unaware of has changed, and if you'll check it somewhere else it will work, and then you'll understand what has changed and maybe how you can make it work anywhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224190/discussion-between-raz-and-lonesome).